# *nix select and exceptfds/errorfds semantics

Tags: c, unix, select, systems-programming

The [select](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/select.html) syscall takes 3 filedescriptor sets for watching fds for readable/writeable and "exceptions" on filedescriptor.

My select [man page](http://web.archive.org/web/20070710123713/http://man.netbsd.se/?find=select%202%2020) doesn't state much about the `exceptfd` descriptor set. What is it used for; what kind of exceptions can and will it notify on file descriptors?

I'm assuming this can be different for the descriptor type... whether it's a TCP socket, a pipe, a tty , etc.). Does anyone have more info on what kind of errors `select` can report on the different kinds of descriptors?

Answer (score 36):

It is sometimes thought that *exceptfds* is needed to detect errors, but that is a misconception.  Errors will be flagged in *readfds*.  Although POSIX requires it (and even calls the parameter *errorfds*), it depends on the OS whether errors are also flagged in *exceptfds*.  Really, this parameter is only needed if you care about *exceptional conditions*, but only rarely is there any need to detect those.

What qualifies as an exceptional condition depends on the kind of file descriptor, but by far the most common use is on a TCP socket where it indicates that out-of-band data is available to be read using `recv()` with the `MSG_OOB` flag.  However, TCP out-of-band data has a number of quirks (e.g. only 1 byte can be outstanding) and as a result is rarely used.

In recent Linux kernels *exceptfds* can be used to detect when certain sysfs attributes change.  The current value of the attribute can be read by reading the appropriate file under `/sys`, and a `select()` on the file descriptor will flag *exceptfds* when the attribute changes.  However this currently only works for some of the attributes, and for mount changes (`/proc/mounts`).

Also some device drivers will flag certain device-specific conditions using *exceptfds*.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it depends on the type of device you're referencing with the file descriptors.  So, it's different for sockets, FIFOs, serial ports, etc...

Look at the man page for read().  At the bottom (at least in OS X) it lists the different errors you can get for different devices.  Same goes for write().

For sockets, FIFOs and other IPC mechanisms, I would check out Unix Network Programming, Volumes 1 and 2.  IIRC it describes what kind of errnos to expect for different error conditions.

I walked this path once with FIFOs.  I ended up brainstorming all the ways the producer and consumer could interact with each end of the FIFO and then wrote test cases for each of those situations.  It was a good (although tedious) way to discover all the different error conditions.  I learned a lot though and ultimately the code just works now.

Comment: while interresting, that does not answer the question. If I understand correctly your answer you're speaking of possible error conditions (errno) triggered on read and that has nothing to do with exceptfds

Comment: This was from seven years ago. I wish I could tell you what I was referring to, but I don't even remember writing this answer. Sorry, I'm not going to be able to clarify my statements for you.