# What's a file descriptor's "exception"?

Tags: c, unix, io, file-descriptor, multiplexing

When one calls select() asking which file descriptors have "exceptions" waiting, what does that mean?

How does one trigger one of these "exceptions"?

If anyone can point me to a nice explanation, that'd be awesome. I've been googling and can't find a thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*nix select and exceptfds/errorfds semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342712/nix-select-and-exceptfds-errorfds-semantics)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short form: exceptional situations occur when a TCP socket recieves out of band data.

If you read the `select` [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html), you will find a reference to another supplementary manual page called `select_tut` with the explanation:

> #### exceptfds
>
> This set is watched for "exceptional conditions".  In practice, only one such exceptional condition is common: the availability of out-of-band (OOB) data for reading from a TCP socket.  See recv(2), send(2), and tcp(7) for more details about OOB data.  (One other less common case where select(2) indicates an exceptional condition occurs with pseudo-terminals in packet mode; see tty_ioctl(4).) After select() has returned, exceptfds will be cleared of all file descriptors except for those for which an exceptional condition has occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed there seems to be very little information on this. Thankfully there's an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342712/nix-select-and-exceptfds-errorfds-semantics) with a very good answer.

In the case of Linux, for example, it can denote out-of-band data being received on a stream socket, or "a state change occuring on a pseudoterminal slave connected to a master that is in packet mode" [(TLPI 63.2.1)](http://man7.org/tlpi/).