# When socket select function returns writefds and errorfds?

Tags: sockets

Socket select function has three arguments: readfds, writefds and errorfds. Readfds is triggered when some data arrived to socket. When writefds and errofds are triggered?

Answer (score 0):

`man select`

> Three independent sets of file descriptors are watched.  Those listed
>          in *readfds* will be watched to see if characters become available for
>          reading (more precisely, to see if a read will not block; in
>          particular, a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file), those in
>          *writefds* will be watched to see if space is available for write
>          (though a large write may still block), and those in *exceptfds* will
>          be watched for exceptions.

(*exceptfds* is your *errorfds*.) Now that leaves open what exceptions might be. See [What's a file descriptor's “exception”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714602/whats-a-file-descriptors-exception) for it.