# Understanding select() function for implement

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, select, io

I'm working on a network project (sockets). I have read some article like [link>>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [link>>](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html) but I can't understand them very well. I want to handle operations server-side and I should understand them. Now I think the ***readfds*** is handles the incoming data operation (Am I right? I don't know) and the ***writefds*** is handles the outgoing data (with send() method) operation (Am I right? I don't know). And the last one; the ***exceptfds*** is handles the socket exceptions like disconnection/close operation (Am I right? I don't know). These are only my quesses, I don't know anything about them (without a article description) and I want to ask them in here to understand. Can anybody help me about this? I'll implement a I/O system server-side (high-performance) and I need to understand them very much! Thanks...

Comment: You got *readfds* and *writefds* right. Link to [an explanation of *exceptfds*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1343995/315052). Also, `select()` is probably not your best choice for a high-performance system. Consider `epoll` (on Linux) or `kqueue` (on bsd) instead. Even `poll()` would probably do a little better than `select()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most general sense, `select()` is a way of having your application wait until something interesting happens. This interesting event can be:

- Data is available on one of the sockets you listed in `readfds`, so attempting to `read()` from that socket will not block.
- Write room becomes available on one of the sockets you listed in `writefds`, so attempting to `write()` to that socket will not block.
- Something unusual (like out-of-band data being received) happens on one of the sockets you listed in `exceptfds`.
- The amount of time you specified in `timeout` has passed, but nothing else has happened.

Comment: What do you think about high-performance sockets? Is select() method is suitable for it? What else?

Comment: There are some techniques (e.g, AIO, `epoll()`, and `kqueue()`) which can end up performing slightly better under very high concurrency, but you are unlikely to ever need them. If you're really interested, though, you may want to check out [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), which abstracts away some of the platform-specific nastiness.